# ¿Como saber todas las interfaces y metodos que implementa un objeto?

Tags: c#, .net

¿Hay alguna manera para saber en tiempo de ejecucion que Interfaces y que metodos implementa una instancia de objeto en un momento dado sin preguntar explicitamente por ellos en el entorno .NET (C#)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si,es posible y sencillo obtener esa información utilizando Reflection. Para obtener los Interfaces, puedes hacer esto:

```
var interfaces = objeto.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```

Igualmente para los métodos:

```
var metodos = objeto.GetType().GetMethods();
```